# how to cut words and characters from a string in java

Tags: java

i want to remove from a string the first word and the first letter from the second word.
any way to do that ?

for example,

```
String a = "hello world!"
```

result must be:

> "orld!"

I tried using the method substring but didn't know how to use it properly.
thanks

Comment: `a.split(" ")[1].substring(1)`

Comment: that works for me except for one exception .. what do i do if the string was just one word ? or one character ? can you help me ? thanks @pbabcdefp

Comment: in that case you must check it yourself before trimming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int index = a.indexOf(" ");
String result = index == -1 || index == a.length() - 1 ? "" : a.substring(index + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String helloWorld = "Hello World!";

String newString = helloWorld.substring ( 7 , helloWorld.length ( ) );
```

EDIT: the first parameter in `substring` is the character you want to begin on, for instance, in `"Hello World!"` the W in World is the 7nth character. The second Parameter is the last character to end on. In this case just choose the length of the String to end on the last character.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
String str = "hello world";
String[] strs = str.split(" ");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(strs[1].substring(1));
for (int i = 2; i < strs.length; i++) {
    builder.append(strs[i]);
}
System.out.println(builder);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String newString = "";
    String s = "I am from China!";
    String[] arr = s.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            continue;
        newString += arr[i] + " ";
    }
    newString = newString.substring(1, newString.length() - 1);
    System.out.println("result:"+newString);
```

result:m from China!

Comment: overcomplicated, there is simpler answer above